# Poisson Process conditional probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I have the problem

```
"Suppose that the number of calls arriving to a telesales call centre follows
a Poisson process with intensity λ = 6 calls per hour. Each caller makes a
purchase with probability 0.4.

Suppose now  that 5 calls arrived in the first hour. What is the probability
that 3 of them made a purchase?"
```

I have set $X_t =$ number of calls by time $ t $ and  $Y_t =$ number of purchases made by time $ t $

So I have $Y_t \sim Po(0.4(6)t)$ and I found that arrival time is exponentially distributed and from that i have the expected arrival $\mu = \frac{1}{2.4}=0.4167$

I then found $$P(Y_1=3)= 0.20914 $$

Im not really sure how to use all this information to get the answer I want, I assume the answer is $$P(Y_1=3|X_1=5)$$ but not sure what to do

Comment: In your last expression  $t$ should be replaced by $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know that $5$ people called you no longer need to use the Poisson distribution. Try answer this question: "$5$ calls arrived in the first hour. Giver that each caller has a $0.4$ probability to make a purchase, what is the probability that $3$ of them made a purchase." If you are still unable to do it I am happy to provide a full solution.

Comment: ok so I would use cumulative binomial probabilities? $ P(Y=3) = ({5\choose3})(0.4)^{3}(0.6)^{2}$ is this correct

Comment: Yes. Do you understand why it is ${5\choose3}(0.4)^3(0.6)^2$?

Comment: yes, because ${5\choose3}$ is the number of different ways in which 3 purchases can occur within the 5 calls

Comment: That's correct.